# Xcode10: build input file double-conversion cannot be found

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Environment**

```
System:
      OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.1
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
      Memory: 554.38 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 9.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.9.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.4.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.0, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.0, watchOS 5.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4907809
      Xcode: 10.0/10A255 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
      react-native: 0.57.0 => 0.57.0
```

**Description**

The cli is broken once I have installed Xcode 10. Creating any new project will render the same issue as it seems to be failing compiling double conversion as illustrated below.

```
❌  error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/rod/dev/react/testing/awesome/node_modules/react-native/third-party/double-conversion-1.1.6/src/strtod.cc'
```

**Reproducible Demo**

- Let you mac update to xcode 10 and command line tools.
- Create brand new project react-native init awesomeApp
- Once it has finished setting up, run cd awesomeApp && react-native run-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

```
$ cd node_modules/react-native/scripts && ./ios-install-third-party.sh && cd ../../../
$ cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh && cd ../../../../
```

I hope that this helps for you when you face the same issue.

Comment: Worked for me as a fix on XCODE 11.3.2 after my build was not finding double-conversion 3rd party package.

Comment: In my case no ios-install-third-party.sh file found in scripts folder, how this file is generated ?